# How to Make Items Random? *School Project*

Tags: python, random

UPDATE: Thanks to a very kind person, I have now properly(?) indented the code!

Before you down vote or disregard this, please help! I'm not very skilled at Python and I have looked through some of the posts that are related to my question.

For a school project, I am required to create three Mad Libs stories and make sure that they are selected at random. I simply do not understand how to make these stories random! I've tried using the import random and the random.choice and things like that but it just does not work! Also, while I was experimenting with this, my Mad Libs will now not run as I would like it to!

Any assistance will be appreciated!

```
print("Welcome to my terrible Mad Libs stories. It is not a smart idea to run through my stories. In fact, it is much more wise for you to do something else.")

def story1 ():
    proper_name = input("Why are you doing this. Enter a name: ")
    adjective1 = input("Seriously. Stop. Enter an adjective: ")
    adjective2 = input("Enter an adjective: ")
    adjective3 = input("Enter an adjective: ")
    adjective4 = input("ADJECTIVES. Enter an adjective: ")
    adjective5 = input("Enter an adjective: ")
    adjective6 = input("Why are there so many adjectives... Enter an adjective: ")
    city = input("Enter a city name: ")
    color = input("Enter a color: ")
    plural_clothing = input("Enter a plural article of clothing: ")
    plural_noun1 = input("Enter a plural noun: ")
    plural_noun2 = input("Last one! Enter a plural noun: ")
    plural_noun3 = input("HAH JUST KIDDING. Last one. Enter a plural noun: ")
    plural_noun4 = input("AHAHAHA THAT WASN'T THE LAST ONE...Enter a plural noun: ")

    print("{} has announced that his {} clothing "
      "store in the heart of downtown {}, is having a {} "
      "sale of all merchandise, including {} suits "
      "and slightly irregular {}. Men's cable-knit "
      "{}, only $15.99. Hand-woven Italian {}, half-price. "
      "Double-breasted cashmere {}, $50.00. Genuine imported "
      " {} {} shoes, {} handkerchiefs, "
      "and women's embroidered {}, all at rock-bottom prices. "
      "This is a chance to get some really {} bargains!".format(
      proper_name, adjective1, city, adjective2, adjective3, plural_clothing, plural_noun1, plural_noun2, plural_noun3, color, adjective4, adjective5, plural_noun4, adjective6))



def story2 ():
    proper_name = input("Enter a name: ")
    disease = input("Enter a disease: ")
    body_part = input("Enter a bodypart: ")
    exclamation = input("Enter an exclamation: ")
    adjective = input("Enter an adjective: ")
    nasty_adjective = input("Enter a nasty adjective: ")
    noun = input("Enter a noun: ")
    plural_noun1 = input("You're still here? You should quit... enter a plural noun: ")
    plural_noun2 = input("Enter another plural noun: ")
    plural_noun3 = input("Almost done... enter another plural noun: ")
    plural_noun4 = input("One more! Enter another plural noun: ")

    print("Medical science and people, but mainly science, have discovered "
      "that smoking cigarettes causes {} (obviously). It is also "
      "bad for your {} and causes pains in the {} "
      "(bet you didn't know that). When mice and cats were exposed to "
      "{} cigarette smoke, they developed {} disease (gasp!). "
      "Tobacco companies have put charcoal {} on the ends of cigarettes, "
      "but they still spend millions of {} advertising their {} "
      "product (gross). If you smoke cigarettes, the tobacco will leave all "
      "kinds of tar and {} in your lungs. This will make you cough "
      "and say, '{}!' Don't smoke cigarettes. Remember, only {} smoke.".format(
      disease, noun, body_part, adjective, proper_name, plural_noun1, plural_noun2, nasty_adjective, plural_noun3, exclamation, plural_noun4))

def story3():
    country = input("I love Mad Libs. Enter a geographic location: ")
    adjective1 = input("The line before this one was false. Enter an adjective: ")
    adjective2 = input("Enter an adjective: ")
    clothing = input("Enter an article of clothing: ")
    number1 = input("Enter a number: ")
    number2 = input("Well, I guess you should enter another number: ")
    plural_noun1 = input("How about a plural noun?: ")
    plural_noun2 = input("Wait, you need another plural noun: ")


    print("Here is tomorrow's weather report for AMERICA "
    "and vicinity. Early tomorrow, a HAPPY front will "
    "collide with a mass of hot PANTS moving from the "
    "north. This means we can expect NICE winds and "
    "occasional BIRDS by late afternoon. Wind velocity will "
    "be 23 miles an hour, and the high temperature should "
    "be around 12 degrees. So, if you're going out, you had "
    "better plan on wearing your SHIRT. ".format(
    country, adjective1, plural_noun1, adjective2, plural_noun2, number1, number2, clothing))
print((story1), (story2), (story3))

import random

story = ['story1', 'story2', 'story3']
print(random.choice(story))
```

Comment: The first thing would be to understand indentations before writing code in python. You might also want to look at basic syntax for example defining arrays in this case.

Comment: The second thing is to make code syntactically correct. There is no such thing in Python as `define story...`

Comment: Could you check if the code here is really what you have? It seems there are some problems like indentationerrors and `define story(story1, story2, story3)` looks like another syntaxerror.

Comment: Do you want the story random? Do you want the arguments passed to the story random? Both?

Comment: To indent the code in the post, highlight the code and press the `{}` button at the top of the editor.

Comment: Please reduce the example code to the minimum example to reproduce your problem. Furthermore, random selection is a very common use case and tutorials should be vast, so rather point out what exact problems you have with your approach. As it stands, this question is no good fit and hence the downvotes.

Comment: "I've tried using the import random and the random.choice and things like that but it just does not work! Also, while I was experimenting with this, my Mad Libs will now not run as I would like it to!" How do you expect us to know "how you would like it to run"? In what way did `random.choice()` not do what you want? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

===============UPDATED=================

For your original code, I think problem mainly happens here:

```
print((story1), (story2), (story3))
```

That calls 3 function, but records nothing, and it's not calling in the right  way, you should:

```
print(story1(), story2(), story3())
```

that could call these functions(just the right format, that does not solve your question).

And for:

```
import random

story = ['story1', 'story2', 'story3']
print(random.choice(story))
```

The question is `'story1'` is a string, so that will only random the 3 strings contented `'story1'`, `'story2'` and  `'story3'`. And, for each function you simply `print()` the joined story, so once you leave that function, that string will no longer exists due to the variable scope. So I made several changes:

```
print("Welcome to my terrible Mad Libs stories. It is not a smart idea to run through my stories. In fact, it is much more wise for you to do something else.")

def story1 ():
    proper_name = input("Why are you doing this. Enter a name: ")
    adjective1 = input("Seriously. Stop. Enter an adjective: ")
    adjective2 = input("Enter an adjective: ")
    adjective3 = input("Enter an adjective: ")
    adjective4 = input("ADJECTIVES. Enter an adjective: ")
    adjective5 = input("Enter an adjective: ")
    adjective6 = input("Why are there so many adjectives... Enter an adjective: ")
    city = input("Enter a city name: ")
    color = input("Enter a color: ")
    plural_clothing = input("Enter a plural article of clothing: ")
    plural_noun1 = input("Enter a plural noun: ")
    plural_noun2 = input("Last one! Enter a plural noun: ")
    plural_noun3 = input("HAH JUST KIDDING. Last one. Enter a plural noun: ")
    plural_noun4 = input("AHAHAHA THAT WASN'T THE LAST ONE...Enter a plural noun: ")

    return '''{} has announced that his {} clothing 
    store in the heart of downtown {}, is having a {} 
    sale of all merchandise, including {} suits 
    and slightly irregular {}. Men's cable-knit {}, 
    only $15.99. Hand-woven Italian {}, half-price. 
    Double-breasted cashmere {}, $50.00. Genuine imported {} 
    {} shoes, {} handkerchiefs, and women's embroidered {}, 
    all at rock-bottom prices. This is a chance to get 
    some really {} bargains!'''.format(proper_name,\
        adjective1, city, adjective2, adjective3, \
        plural_clothing, plural_noun1, plural_noun2, \
        plural_noun3, color, adjective4, adjective5, \
        plural_noun4, adjective6)

def story2 ():
    proper_name = input("Enter a name: ")
    disease = input("Enter a disease: ")
    body_part = input("Enter a bodypart: ")
    exclamation = input("Enter an exclamation: ")
    adjective = input("Enter an adjective: ")
    nasty_adjective = input("Enter a nasty adjective: ")
    noun = input("Enter a noun: ")
    plural_noun1 = input("You're still here? You should quit... enter a plural noun: ")
    plural_noun2 = input("Enter another plural noun: ")
    plural_noun3 = input("Almost done... enter another plural noun: ")
    plural_noun4 = input("One more! Enter another plural noun: ")

    return '''Medical science and people, but mainly science,
    have discovered that smoking cigarettes causes {}
    (obviously). It is also bad for your {} 
    and causes pains in the {} (bet you didn't know that).
    When mice and cats were exposed to {} cigarette smoke, 
    they developed {} disease (gasp!). Tobacco companies
    have put charcoal {} on the ends of cigarettes,
    but they still spend millions of {} advertising 
    their {} product (gross). If you smoke cigarettes,
    the tobacco will leave all kinds of tar and {} 
    in your lungs. This will make you cough and say,
    '{}!' Don't smoke cigarettes. Remember, only {} 
    smoke.'''.format(disease,noun, body_part, adjective,\
        proper_name, plural_noun1, plural_noun2, nasty_adjective, \
        plural_noun3, exclamation, plural_noun4)


def story3():
    country = input("I love Mad Libs. Enter a geographic location: ")
    adjective1 = input("The line before this one was false. Enter an adjective: ")
    adjective2 = input("Enter an adjective: ")
    clothing = input("Enter an article of clothing: ")
    number1 = input("Enter a number: ")
    number2 = input("Well, I guess you should enter another number: ")
    plural_noun1 = input("How about a plural noun?: ")
    plural_noun2 = input("Wait, you need another plural noun: ")

    #I don't know where youre gonna put these words...
    return '''{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}Here is tomorrow's weather report for 
    AMERICA and vicinity. Early tomorrow, a HAPPY front 
    will collide with a mass of hot PANTS moving 
    from the north. This means we can expect NICE 
    winds and occasional BIRDS by late afternoon. 
    Wind velocity will be 23 miles an hour, and the 
    high temperature should be around 12 degrees.
    So, if you're going out, you had better plan on 
    wearing your SHIRT.'''.format(country, adjective1, \
        plural_noun1, adjective2, plural_noun2, number1, \
        number2, clothing)


storyOne = story1().replace('\n','').replace('    ','')
storyTwo = story2().replace('\n','').replace('    ','')
storyThree = story3().replace('\n','').replace('    ','')

import random

story = [storyOne, storyTwo, storyThree]
print(random.choice(story))
```

Now every function returns a string, and use `storyThree = story3().replace('\n','').replace('    ','')` to record that, hence `storyOne`, `storyTwo` and `storyThree` are 3 variable, so it can be put into a list, then `random.choice(story)` would work.